# JQuery Mobile - opening panel jumps page to top

Tags: jquery-mobile, panel

When I'm scroll down page a little and then tap on open panel button page jumps to top.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" id="mypanel">
test panelu
</div>
<div data-role="header" role="banner" data-position="fixed">
<a href="#mypanel" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all"><img id="menu-button" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/gfx/menu.svg"></a>
<h1><a id="header-logo" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/index.php?template=xxxx">Some name</a></h1>
</div>
<jdoc:include type="message" />
<jdoc:include type="component" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `data-position-fixed="true"` in panel div line:

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" data-position-fixed="true" id="mypanel">
test panelu
</div>
<div data-role="header" role="banner" data-position="fixed">
<a href="#mypanel" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all"><img id="menu-button" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/gfx/menu.svg"></a>
<h1><a id="header-logo" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/index.php?template=xxxx">Some name</a></h1>
</div>
<jdoc:include type="message" />
<jdoc:include type="component" />
</div>
```